# Can my Android app open a URL in an incognito tab?

Tags: android, browser, android-3.0-honeycomb

We all know how to open a URL in the browser in Andriod.  Do something like this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Honeycomb's stock browser includes support for incognito mode.  Is there a way to make the target URL open in an incognito tab?  I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there's no incognito mode for stock Android Browser so probably you cant do that.Just Honeycomb and above version browsers have that feature.

Comment: Honeycomb has incognito mode, I'll add that to my question.

Comment: only cyanogen have incognito mode

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no incognito mode in the stock Android browser.

There are several apps supplying this feature - they should offer themselves when you fire the Intent you gave in the code.

Comment: Honeycomb has incognito mode, I'll add that to my question.