# How to open a web page in Google chrome incognito from android app

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

I have spent much time on this and unable to figured out about this.

I need to launch chrome browser in incognito mode.

My Code:

```
    private void launchBrowser() {
    String url = "http://foyr.com";
    Intent launchGoogleChrome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    launchGoogleChrome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    launchGoogleChrome.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    try {
        startActivity(launchGoogleChrome);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        launchGoogleChrome.setPackage(null);
        startActivity(launchGoogleChrome);
    }
}
```

i found several posts on this but am unable to find the solution.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127654/can-my-android-app-open-a-url-in-an-incognito-tab)

This [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/3812747c8aaaa5e9aeb370442c1c8cdc2483b9a0/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ServiceTabLauncher.java) gives me some idea about incognito mode but i tried this also.

```
    private void launchBrowser() {
    String url = "http://foyr.com";
    Intent launchGoogleChrome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    launchGoogleChrome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    launchGoogleChrome.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    launchGoogleChrome.putExtra("com.android.chrome.EXTRA_OPEN_NEW_INCOGNITO_TAB", true);
    try {
        startActivity(launchGoogleChrome);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        launchGoogleChrome.setPackage(null);
        startActivity(launchGoogleChrome);
    }
}
```

But chrome browser is not receiving any intent info from app. can any one help me where am wrong and what to do?

Comment: There might be a solution using ```EXTRA_OPEN_NEW_INCOGNITO_TAB``` but I think it's not possible from outside of chrome

Comment: Yes..is there any android intent which navigates to incognito?

Comment: similar questions have been posted since years ago and no even 1 expert could answer to these question. i'm curious now.. perhaps there is no solution for this at all.

Answer (score 4):

From the source code :

```
// "Open new incognito tab" is currently limited to Chrome or first parties.
if (!isInternal
        && IntentUtils.safeGetBooleanExtra(
                   intent, EXTRA_OPEN_NEW_INCOGNITO_TAB, false)) {
    return true;
}
```

It seems the extra will do nothing unless you are forking Chrome or explicitly allowed to by Google.

Comment: Link to Chromium code in question: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/IntentHandler.java;l=918-931

Comment: Link to Chromium commit that made this change: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/1b2247e8e0a7277aa58ce4fcb242c7be2dafe564