# Is there a way to open an URL in Private Window/Ingognito Window with Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm completely new in Java/Kotlin development (I try to learn both: basics and structure in Java, then I apply it to Kotlin).

I want to create an Android app in Android Studio 3.0 and I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Kotlin:

I have a button called button1.

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
            web_page("http://google.com")
    }
```

And this function:

```
fun web_page(url: String) {
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

It works. But I want the link to open in an ingognito windows.

Comment: What does "open an URL in private windows with Java?" mean?

Comment: When someone tap a button I want to open an URL link in Chrome (or the default browser) in an Ingonito Mode/Private Window

Comment: Please attach the code which you tried

Comment: There are many Web browsers for Android, including several "default" browsers. None have to offer any form of incognito or private browsing capability. None have to expose that capability to third-party apps.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/9DD9j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might be helpful to you

[How to open a web page in Google chrome incognito from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696033/how-to-open-a-web-page-in-google-chrome-incognito-from-android-app)

> Open new incognito tab" is currently limited to Chrome or first parties.