# Use a browser to open the url and enter the incognito mode

Tags: flutter

Use [url_launcher](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/url_launcher) to open the url in flutter, but I want to open it in incognito mode, what do I need to do, thanks

I am using an Android device

Comment: I'm not aware of any way you can force this.

Comment: In webView , you have an option, but i dont know about url_laucher

Comment: Add `--incognito` to enter incognito mode when starting on PC, I don’t know how to do it in Flutter

Comment: Do you mean Chrome on Android, or *any* browser on Android? If latter, actually some browsers does *not* have such a incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Case A: If you mean Chrome on Android: It is impossible, even if you are writing native java code: [How to open a web page in Google chrome incognito from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696033/how-to-open-a-web-page-in-google-chrome-incognito-from-android-app).

Case B: If you mean *any* browser on Android, actually some browsers does not have such a incognito mode. For those browsers which supports incognito mode, you may try to search for that *particular* browser.

Actually, why do you want to open incognito? Maybe you can just use the in-app browser package of Flutter, instead of opening an external browser.