# Android- How to launch the URL in browser which does not stores in browser history

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am launching a URL in a web browser from my application.

When I open Chrome on the phone, the URL is still showing in the browser and this causes security problems in the app. How can I restrict the web browser and not to store the url in web browser.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: code snip pls ?

Comment: webView does not show url. Use webView in a new Activity.

Comment: Yes but l dont want show using webview .@Saurabh Bhandari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my Android app open a URL in an incognito tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127654/can-my-android-app-open-a-url-in-an-incognito-tab)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you have to use your custom `WebView`, because every third party Browser have its own property to store Url, I guess android didn't have have any property to restrict third party browser.

Please use Webview like this, and create your Web Client for more customization

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

For more advanced processing for the web content, consider the `ChromeClient`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid security problems in your application, you should use the WebView. Because Android does not allow to clear the third-party application cache or history.

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

wv.loadUrl("http://yoururl");
```

Well, you can also clear the cache of the WebView by using the clearCache method.

```
void clearCache (boolean includeDiskFiles)
```

Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html for more.